# How can I turn on ECN for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, tcp

I'd like to run some networking tests with Mac OSX 10.8 and using the ECN option. However I cannot find any documentation on how to configure it.

Does anybody know how to alter Mac OSX TCP networking options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick searching I´ve found the following [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification#Mac_OS_X) which suggests the following sysctl settings:

> net.inet.tcp.ecn_negotiate_in
>
> net.inet.tcp.ecn_initiate_out

You could set these up with:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.ecn_negotiate_in=1
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.ecn_initiate_out=1
```

These setting will disappear after reboot.